# How to show external links as popup in react application?

Tags: reactjs, popup

In my react application, when I click on an external link suppose http://www.example.com/about, I do not want it to redirect to that website but I want that about page to render as a popup in my react application. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might make a wrapper component for the links that would check if the `href` prop matches your website location or goes to a 3rd party site, and renders either a normal `a` tag or a modal dialog with an iframe inside.

Eg. `Link.js`

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import Modal from '...' // any of the available modal component for react

export default class Link extends Component {
  state = { isOpen: false }

  render () {
    const url = new URL(this.props.href)
    if (url.hostname === WEBSITE_HOSTNAME) return (
      <a href={this.props.href}>{this.props.children}</a>
    )

    return (
      <Fragment>
        // you could also use an <a> here if you want users to be able to open the link in a new tab with a right click
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ modalOpen: true })}>{this.props.children}</button>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>
          <iframe src={this.props.href} />
        </Modal>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Even better, split it into two components as there's no need for regular links to have any state...

Comment: I passed props in constructor and super, but it says props is not defined

Comment: Change `new URL(props.href)` to `new URL(this.props.href)` - I've updated my answer. This was intended more as a generalized answer on how you might approach the issue, not a direct snippet of code to use as is, though :)